Extract and merge multipe tar gz
I have multiple tar.gz archives, the size of each archive is approximately 40 GB:
v1.0-trainval01_blobs.tgz
v1.0-trainval01_blobs.tgz
...
v1.0-trainval10_blobs.tgz

I can unpack each archive and get the following directory structure:
v1.0-trainval01_blobs
   samples
   sweeps
v1.0-trainval02_blobs
   samples
   sweeps
...
v1.0-trainval10_blobs
   samples
   sweeps

This unpacking will consume many hours, even days. But this is not enough! Next I have to merge samples and sweeps folders:
v1.0-trainval_all_blobs
   samples
   sweeps

And this is time-consuming operation again... Do I can unpack contents of all tar.gz in  v1.0-trainval_all_blobs via the single command?

Sounds like a job for bsdtar which can make an archive out of other archives with the tar -cjf out.tar.xz @in1.tar.gz @in2.tar.bz2 and rename archive members on the fly with -s. Combined, you'll have a resulting merged archive without ever extracting a single file to disk

If you have GNU tar, you could do something like: for f in v1.0-trainval*_blobs.tgz; do tar xvfz "$f" --transform 's/^v1.0-trainval[0-9.]\+/v1.0-trainval_all/'; done (or the --strip-components + -C option in the other answer)
